# How to create a Marimekko/Mosaic plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

The Marimekko/Mosaic plot is a nice default plot when both x and y are categorical variables. What is the best way to create these using ggplot?

[image: example]

The only reference I could find was this 4yo [blog post](http://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/ggplot2_marimekko_mosaic_chart/) but this seems a bit outdated. Are there any better or easier implementations avaialable by now? The GGally package has a function `ggally_ratio` but this produces something quite different:

[image: ggally]

Comment: Have you tried  `graphics::mosaicplot` ?

Comment: I'd like to stick with `ggplot2` to be able to extend it with other features (faceting, etc)

Comment: Not a great answer but see http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/prodplots.html

Comment: See [here](http://rcharts.io/viewer/?5862751) for an interactive version of Marimekko Plot using `rCharts` and `dimplejs`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I had the same issue for a project some time back. My solution was to use `geom_bar` together with the `scales="free_x", space="free_x"` option in `facet_grid` to accommodate different bar widths:

```
# using diamonds dataset for illustration
df <- diamonds %>%
  group_by(cut, clarity) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  mutate(cut.count = sum(count),
         prop = count/sum(count)) %>%
  ungroup()

ggplot(df,
       aes(x = cut, y = prop, width = cut.count, fill = clarity)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "fill", colour = "black") +
  # geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(prop)), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) + # if labels are desired
  facet_grid(~cut, scales = "free_x", space = "free_x") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "RdYlGn") +
  # theme(panel.spacing.x = unit(0, "npc")) + # if no spacing preferred between bars
  theme_void()
```

[image: marimekko plot]

Comment: Hi, I am reading this answer a few years later after you posted it. r does not recognize %>%. what should I do?

Comment: @Hamed Do you have `dplyr` or `magrittr` package loaded? Either should enable R to recognize the pipe operator.

Answer (score 29):

I did it myself a time ago, using just `geom_bar`, I turned it into a general function so it should work on any two `factors`. [image]

```
ggMMplot <- function(var1, var2){
  require(ggplot2)
  levVar1 <- length(levels(var1))
  levVar2 <- length(levels(var2))

  jointTable <- prop.table(table(var1, var2))
  plotData <- as.data.frame(jointTable)
  plotData$marginVar1 <- prop.table(table(var1))
  plotData$var2Height <- plotData$Freq / plotData$marginVar1
  plotData$var1Center <- c(0, cumsum(plotData$marginVar1)[1:levVar1 -1]) +
    plotData$marginVar1 / 2

  ggplot(plotData, aes(var1Center, var2Height)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(width = marginVar1, fill = var2), col = "Black") +
    geom_text(aes(label = as.character(var1), x = var1Center, y = 1.05)) 
  }

ggMMplot(diamonds$cut, diamonds$clarity)
```

Comment: Thanks! Have updated this a little to tidy the labelling and permit easy specification of a colour scale via colour brewer - download via [this gist](https://gist.github.com/docsteveharris/4e12c86ac2dd96bfa2dd5cbf13ba3e53)

Comment: There is a warning.  "Ignoring unknown aesthetics: width".  Perhaps this could be updated.

Comment: I think Z.Lin does a great job with a current R / tidyverse implementation.

Answer (score 13):

A first attempt. I'm not sure how to put the factor labels on the axis though.

```
makeplot_mosaic <- function(data, x, y, ...){
  xvar <- deparse(substitute(x))
  yvar <- deparse(substitute(y))
  mydata <- data[c(xvar, yvar)];
  mytable <- table(mydata);
  widths <- c(0, cumsum(apply(mytable, 1, sum)));
  heights <- apply(mytable, 1, function(x){c(0, cumsum(x/sum(x)))});

  alldata <- data.frame();
  allnames <- data.frame();
  for(i in 1:nrow(mytable)){
    for(j in 1:ncol(mytable)){
      alldata <- rbind(alldata, c(widths[i], widths[i+1], heights[j, i], heights[j+1, i]));
    }
  }
  colnames(alldata) <- c("xmin", "xmax", "ymin", "ymax")

  alldata[[xvar]] <- rep(dimnames(mytable)[[1]],rep(ncol(mytable), nrow(mytable)));
  alldata[[yvar]] <- rep(dimnames(mytable)[[2]],nrow(mytable));

  ggplot(alldata, aes(xmin=xmin, xmax=xmax, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax)) + 
    geom_rect(color="black", aes_string(fill=yvar)) +
    xlab(paste(xvar, "(count)")) + ylab(paste(yvar, "(proportion)"));
}
```

Example:

```
makeplot_mosaic(mtcars, vs, gear)
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 9):

You may use the ggplot2 extension package called "ggmosaic" (https://github.com/haleyjeppson/ggmosaic).

Extensive tutorial with example code and visual results is given here https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggmosaic/vignettes/ggmosaic.html.

Comment: This could be a good answer but ggmosaic is a little complicated, perhaps you should explain how to get the plot with it, or at least give a usable code line.

Comment: In all fairness, the question was raised without reproduceable code. I added reference to the package tutorial which will help to get the problem solved.

Answer (score 6):

[Plotluck](https://github.com/stefan-schroedl/plotluck) is a library based on *ggplot2* that aims at automating the choice of plot type based on characteristics of 1-3 variables. It contains a function for mosaic plots. Example:
`plotluck(mtcars,vs,gear)`

[image]

Comment: Fantastic library! It is precisely what I have been looking for! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

Following [user2030503](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2030503/user2030503)'s suggestion, here's a version that uses `ggmosaic`.  (Note that [ggplot 3.0 broke some piece of ggmosaic](https://github.com/haleyjeppson/ggmosaic/issues/9), so you need the most recent version.)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggmosaic)

# Data copied from linked blog post
df <- data.frame(
  segment = LETTERS[1:4],
  segpct = c(40, 30, 20, 10),
  Alpha = c(60, 40, 30, 25), 
  Beta = c(25, 30, 30, 25),
  Gamma = c(10, 20, 20, 25), 
  Delta = c(5, 10, 20, 25)
  )

# Convert to "long" for plotting
df_long <- gather(df, key = "greek_letter", value = "pct", 
                  -c("segment", "segpct")) %>% 
  mutate(
    greek_letter = factor(
      greek_letter, 
      levels = c("Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Delta")
      ),
    weight = (segpct * pct) / 10000
    )

# Plot
ggplot(df_long) +
  geom_mosaic(aes(x = product(greek_letter, segment), fill = greek_letter,
                  weight = weight))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Thanks all who created this entry which really helped me as ggmosaic wasn't doing what I wanted (and not labelling axes properly).  The nice function from Z.Lin throws a warning sort of explained in https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3142 which seems to say that warning, which is technically untrue in its content, is really warning us that the ggplotocracy, bless and thank them, feel that geom_bar shouldn't really have variable widths.  I guess I see the point so I went for the function from Jake Fisher and tweaked it to my own needs.  In case it's useful to others, here it is:

```
makeplot_mosaic2 <- function(data, x, y, statDigits = 1, residDigits = 1, pDigits = 3, ...){
  ### from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233365/how-to-create-a-marimekko-mosaic-plot-in-ggplot2,
  ### this from Jake Fisher (I think)
  xvar <- deparse(substitute(x))
  yvar <- deparse(substitute(y))
  mydata <- data[c(xvar, yvar)]
  mytable <- table(mydata)
  
  widths <- c(0, cumsum(apply(mytable, 1, sum)))
  heights <- apply(mytable, 1, function(x){c(0, cumsum(x/sum(x)))})
  
  alldata <- data.frame()
  allnames <- data.frame()
  for(i in 1:nrow(mytable)){
    for(j in 1:ncol(mytable)){
      alldata <- rbind(alldata, c(widths[i], widths[i+1], heights[j, i], heights[j+1, i]))
    }
  }
  colnames(alldata) <- c("xmin", "xmax", "ymin", "ymax")
  
  alldata[[xvar]] <- rep(dimnames(mytable)[[1]],rep(ncol(mytable), nrow(mytable)))
  alldata[[yvar]] <- rep(dimnames(mytable)[[2]],nrow(mytable))
  
  chisq <- chisq.test(mytable)
  df <- chisq$parameter
  pval <- chisq$p.value
  chisqval <- chisq$statistic
  # stdResids <- chisq$stdres
  alldata$xcent <- (alldata$xmin + alldata$xmax)/2
  alldata$ycent <- (alldata$ymin + alldata$ymax)/2
  alldata$stdres <- round(as.vector(t(chisq$stdres)), residDigits)
  # print(chisq$stdres)
  # print(alldata)
  
  titleTxt1 <- paste0("Mosaic plot of ",
                      yvar,
                      " against ",
                      xvar,
                      ", ")
  titleTxt2 <- paste0("chisq(",
                     df,
                     ") = ",
                     round(chisqval, statDigits),
                     ", p = ",
                     format.pval(pval, digits = pDigits))
  titleTxt <- paste0(titleTxt1, titleTxt2)
  subTitleTxt <- "Cell labels are standardised residuals"
  
  ggplot(data  = alldata, 
         aes(xmin=xmin, xmax=xmax, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax)) + 
    geom_rect(color="black", aes_string(fill=yvar)) +
    geom_text(aes(x = xcent, y = ycent, label = stdres)) +
    xlab(paste0("Count of '", 
                xvar,
                "', total = ",
                max(alldata$xmax))) + # tweaked by CE
    ylab(paste0("Proportion of '", 
                yvar,
                "' per level of '",
                xvar,
                "'")) +
    ggtitle(titleTxt,
            subtitle = subTitleTxt) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = .5),
          plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = .5))
}

makeplot_mosaic2(mtcars, vs, gear)
makeplot_mosaic2(diamonds, cut, clarity)
```

Comment: Whoops, probably should have said that my tweaks are to label the cells with the standardised residuals, add a title and subtitle and to tweak the axis labels.