# How to plot a mosaic plot from pre-calculated count data?

Tags: r, import, plot

I would like to create a simple mosaic plot from the data file below:

```
Country|Name|Count
US|Sam|10
US|John|30
UK|Sam|30
UK|John|2
CA|Sam|23
CA|Bill|45
```

I expect to get a mosaic plot with 1st column on x-axis and stacked rectangle of height "Count" for each category "Name".

I tried:

```
data<-read.table("my_table.txt", header=T, sep="|")
mosaicplot(data)
```

But it creates a monster with way too many columns and rows.

My question is how to mention that values of the "Count" variable should be the y values?
I tried to use `ftable(graph)` before making the mosaic but even the table is not well ordered.

Comment: Answering based on your title: The importing is done correctly, using str(data) you can see:'data.frame': 6 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Country: Factor w/ 3 levels "CA","UK","US": 3 3 2 2 1 1
 $ Name   : Factor w/ 3 levels "Bill","John",..: 3 2 3 2 3 1
 $ Count  : int  10 30 30 2 23 45
I suggest to change your title to match your question about the mosaicplot

Comment: [Product plots](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/prodplots.pdf) and [How to create a Marimekko/Mosaic plot in ggplot2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233365/how-to-create-a-marimekko-mosaic-plot-in-ggplot2) might be relevant.

Comment: Thanks! I got the principle of mosaic chart, just not the way to define "Count" as the y variable.

Comment: Although I guess there are no direct ways to do mosaics, I think a ggplot equivalent to define the data would be something like:`ggplot(data=data, aes(x=Name, y=Count, group=Country)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to 'explode' your pre-calculated data using `rep`.

```
country <- with(df, rep(x = Country, times = Count))
name <- with(df, rep(x = Name, times = Count))

df2 <- data.frame(country, name)
mosaicplot(country ~ name, data = df2)
```

[image]

Comment: Great to hear that it worked the way you wanted! Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest `spine` function from the `vcd` library:

```
# require(vcd)
dt <- xtabs(Count~Name+Country, data=data)
spine(dt)
```

`?spine` "Spine plots are a special cases of mosaic plots, and can be seen as a generalization of stacked (or highlighted) bar plots. Analogously, spinograms are an extension of histograms."

`spineplot` function is also available in the base graphics.

[image]

Comment: Thansk TWL! Although the axis are inverted (just need to change their order in stabs I presume), this function is very handy.

Comment: @lqdo2000, you're welcome, and indeed, try `xtabs(Count~Country+Name, data=data)` to change the order.