# Add a numeric axis to a mosaicplot

Tags: r, plot, axis, mosaic-plot

I am plotting data using a mosaic plot (with `mosaicplot()`) and am considering adding a numeric axis to one dimension to clarify the size of the different groups. But, I do not understand how the plot cells are aligned to the axis since it seems to range from approximately 0.2 to .98 (or something like that) on the graphics device. Here's a reproducible example:

```
mosaicplot(Titanic, main = "Survival on the Titanic", off = 0)
axis(1, seq(0, 1, by = 0.1))
```

Note how a 0-1 x-axis actually extends to the left and right of the plot. Is it possible to add a set of axis labels that is scaled correctly?

[image]

Comment: you could circumvent this if used a custom ggplot solution as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233365/how-to-create-a-marimekko-mosaic-plot-in-ggplot2)

Answer (score 3):

```
par(mfrow = c(2,1), mar = c(3,4,2,1))
mp(Titanic)
mp(Titanic, off = 0)
```

[image]

This one isn't difficult to fix, but there are a couple things going on:

1. obviously, the axis doesn't start at 0 nor does it end at something round which is what you get from `pretty` (used to calculate, draw, and label the ticks and labels). From these lines, we can see that the polygons are drawn from 50 to 950 along the x (depending on what is set for `cex.axis`):

---

```
  x1 <- 30 + 20 * cex.axis/0.66
  y1 <- 5
  x2 <- 950
  y2 <- 1000 - x1
```

2. Secondly, the plotting device is finished when the function exits which is why your attempt ranges from 0 to 1 instead of `pretty(c(50, 950))`, and I don't see any way to pass something through `mosaicplot` like `new` or `add` since

> Warning message:
>   In mosaicplot.default(Titanic, new = TRUE) :
>     extra argument ‘new’ will be disregarded

---

So I don't think there is an easy fix without editing the source code (because seems like you would have to backtrace how far over your last plot has shifted the origin and how that translates to a new window which may not be the same for every plot and blah blah blah).

The only thing I changed was adding the final three lines.

```
## graphics:::mosaicplot.default
mp <- function (x, main = deparse(substitute(x)), sub = NULL, xlab = NULL,
          ylab = NULL, sort = NULL, off = NULL, dir = NULL, color = NULL, 
          shade = FALSE, margin = NULL, cex.axis = 0.66, las = par("las"), 
          border = NULL, type = c("pearson", "deviance", "FT"), ...) {
  mosaic.cell <- function(X, x1, y1, x2, y2, srt.x, srt.y, 
                          adj.x, adj.y, off, dir, color, lablevx, lablevy, maxdim, 
                          currlev, label) {
    p <- ncol(X) - 2
    if (dir[1L] == "v") {
      xdim <- maxdim[1L]
      XP <- rep.int(0, xdim)
      for (i in seq_len(xdim)) XP[i] <- sum(X[X[, 1L] == 
                                                i, p])/sum(X[, p])
      if (anyNA(XP)) 
        stop("missing values in contingency table")
      white <- off[1L] * (x2 - x1)/max(1, xdim - 1)
      x.l <- x1
      x.r <- x1 + (1 - off[1L]) * XP[1L] * (x2 - x1)
      if (xdim > 1L) 
        for (i in 2:xdim) {
          x.l <- c(x.l, x.r[i - 1L] + white)
          x.r <- c(x.r, x.r[i - 1L] + white + (1 - off[1L]) * 
                     XP[i] * (x2 - x1))
        }
      if (lablevx > 0L) {
        this.lab <- if (is.null(label[[1L]][1L])) {
          paste(rep.int(as.character(currlev), length(currlev)), 
                as.character(seq_len(xdim)), sep = ".")
        }
        else label[[1L]]
        text(x = x.l + (x.r - x.l)/2, y = 1000 - 35 * 
               cex.axis/0.66 + 22 * cex.axis/0.65 * (lablevx - 
                                                       1), srt = srt.x, adj = adj.x, cex = cex.axis, 
             this.lab, xpd = NA)
      }
      if (p > 2L) {
        for (i in seq_len(xdim)) {
          if (XP[i] > 0) {
            Recall(X[X[, 1L] == i, 2L:(p + 2L), drop = FALSE], 
                   x.l[i], y1, x.r[i], y2, srt.x, srt.y, adj.x, 
                   adj.y, off[-1L], dir[-1L], color, lablevx - 
                     1, (i == 1L) * lablevy, maxdim[-1L], 
                   currlev + 1, label[2:p])
          }
          else {
            segments(rep.int(x.l[i], 3L), y1 + (y2 - 
                                                  y1) * c(0, 2, 4)/5, rep.int(x.l[i], 3L), 
                     y1 + (y2 - y1) * c(1, 3, 5)/5)
          }
        }
      }
      else {
        for (i in seq_len(xdim)) {
          if (XP[i] > 0) {
            polygon(c(x.l[i], x.r[i], x.r[i], x.l[i]), 
                    c(y1, y1, y2, y2), lty = if (extended) 
                      X[i, p + 1L]
                    else 1L, col = color[if (extended) 
                      X[i, p + 2L]
                      else i], border = border)
          }
          else {
            segments(rep.int(x.l[i], 3L), y1 + (y2 - 
                                                  y1) * c(0, 2, 4)/5, rep.int(x.l[i], 3L), 
                     y1 + (y2 - y1) * c(1, 3, 5)/5)
          }
        }
      }
    }
    else {
      ydim <- maxdim[1L]
      YP <- rep.int(0, ydim)
      for (j in seq_len(ydim)) {
        YP[j] <- sum(X[X[, 1L] == j, p])/sum(X[, p])
      }
      white <- off[1L] * (y2 - y1)/(max(1, ydim - 1))
      y.b <- y2 - (1 - off[1L]) * YP[1L] * (y2 - y1)
      y.t <- y2
      if (ydim > 1L) {
        for (j in 2:ydim) {
          y.b <- c(y.b, y.b[j - 1] - white - (1 - off[1L]) * 
                     YP[j] * (y2 - y1))
          y.t <- c(y.t, y.b[j - 1] - white)
        }
      }
      if (lablevy > 0L) {
        this.lab <- if (is.null(label[[1L]][1L])) {
          paste(rep.int(as.character(currlev), length(currlev)), 
                as.character(seq_len(ydim)), sep = ".")
        }
        else label[[1L]]
        text(x = 35 * cex.axis/0.66 - 20 * cex.axis/0.66 * 
               (lablevy - 1), y = y.b + (y.t - y.b)/2, srt = srt.y, 
             adj = adj.y, cex = cex.axis, this.lab, xpd = NA)
      }
      if (p > 2L) {
        for (j in seq_len(ydim)) {
          if (YP[j] > 0) {
            Recall(X[X[, 1L] == j, 2:(p + 2), drop = FALSE], 
                   x1, y.b[j], x2, y.t[j], srt.x, srt.y, adj.x, 
                   adj.y, off[-1L], dir[-1L], color, (j == 
                                                        1L) * lablevx, lablevy - 1, maxdim[-1L], 
                   currlev + 1, label[2:p])
          }
          else {
            segments(x1 + (x2 - x1) * c(0, 2, 4)/5, rep.int(y.b[j], 
                                                            3L), x1 + (x2 - x1) * c(1, 3, 5)/5, rep.int(y.b[j], 
                                                                                                        3L))
          }
        }
      }
      else {
        for (j in seq_len(ydim)) {
          if (YP[j] > 0) {
            polygon(c(x1, x2, x2, x1), c(y.b[j], y.b[j], 
                                         y.t[j], y.t[j]), lty = if (extended) 
                                           X[j, p + 1]
                    else 1, col = color[if (extended) 
                      X[j, p + 2]
                      else j], border = border)
          }
          else {
            segments(x1 + (x2 - x1) * c(0, 2, 4)/5, rep.int(y.b[j], 
                                                            3L), x1 + (x2 - x1) * c(1, 3, 5)/5, rep.int(y.b[j], 
                                                                                                        3L))
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  srt.x <- if (las > 1) 
    90
  else 0
  srt.y <- if (las == 0 || las == 3) 
    90
  else 0
  if (is.null(dim(x))) 
    x <- as.array(x)
  else if (is.data.frame(x)) 
    x <- data.matrix(x)
  dimd <- length(dx <- dim(x))
  if (dimd == 0L || any(dx == 0L)) 
    stop("'x' must not have 0 dimensionality")
  if (!missing(...)) 
    warning(sprintf(ngettext(length(list(...)), "extra argument %s will be disregarded", 
                             "extra arguments %s will be disregarded"), paste(sQuote(names(list(...))), 
                                                                              collapse = ", ")), domain = NA)
  Ind <- 1L:dx[1L]
  if (dimd > 1L) {
    Ind <- rep.int(Ind, prod(dx[2:dimd]))
    for (i in 2:dimd) {
      Ind <- cbind(Ind, c(matrix(1L:dx[i], byrow = TRUE, 
                                 nrow = prod(dx[1L:(i - 1)]), ncol = prod(dx[i:dimd]))))
    }
  }
  Ind <- cbind(Ind, c(x))
  if (is.logical(shade) && !shade) {
    extended <- FALSE
    Ind <- cbind(Ind, NA, NA)
  }
  else {
    if (is.logical(shade)) 
      shade <- c(2, 4)
    else if (any(shade <= 0) || length(shade) > 5) 
      stop("invalid 'shade' specification")
    extended <- TRUE
    shade <- sort(shade)
    breaks <- c(-Inf, -rev(shade), 0, shade, Inf)
    color <- c(hsv(0, s = seq.int(1, to = 0, length.out = length(shade) + 
                                    1)), hsv(4/6, s = seq.int(0, to = 1, length.out = length(shade) + 
                                                                1)))
    if (is.null(margin)) 
      margin <- as.list(1L:dimd)
    E <- stats::loglin(x, margin, fit = TRUE, print = FALSE)$fit
    type <- match.arg(type)
    residuals <- switch(type, pearson = (x - E)/sqrt(E), 
                        deviance = {
                          tmp <- 2 * (x * log(ifelse(x == 0, 1, x/E)) - 
                                        (x - E))
                          tmp <- sqrt(pmax(tmp, 0))
                          ifelse(x > E, tmp, -tmp)
                        }, FT = sqrt(x) + sqrt(x + 1) - sqrt(4 * E + 1))
    Ind <- cbind(Ind, c(1 + (residuals < 0)), as.numeric(cut(residuals, 
                                                             breaks)))
  }
  label <- dimnames(x)
  if (is.null(off)) 
    off <- if (dimd == 2) 
      2 * (dx - 1)
  else rep.int(10, dimd)
  if (length(off) != dimd) 
    off <- rep_len(off, dimd)
  if (any(off > 50)) 
    off <- off * 50/max(off)
  if (is.null(dir) || length(dir) != dimd) {
    dir <- rep_len(c("v", "h"), dimd)
  }
  if (!is.null(sort)) {
    if (length(sort) != dimd) 
      stop("length of 'sort' does not conform to 'dim(x)'")
    Ind[, seq_len(dimd)] <- Ind[, sort]
    off <- off[sort]
    dir <- dir[sort]
    label <- label[sort]
  }
  nam.dn <- names(label)
  if (is.null(xlab) && any(dir == "v")) 
    xlab <- nam.dn[min(which(dir == "v"))]
  if (is.null(ylab) && any(dir == "h")) 
    ylab <- nam.dn[min(which(dir == "h"))]
  ncolors <- length(tabulate(Ind[, dimd]))
  if (!extended && ((is.null(color) || length(color) != ncolors))) {
    color <- if (is.logical(color)) 
      if (color[1L]) 
        gray.colors(ncolors)
    else rep.int(0, ncolors)
    else if (is.null(color)) 
      rep.int("grey", ncolors)
    else rep_len(color, ncolors)
  }
  dev.hold()
  on.exit(dev.flush())
  plot.new()
  if (!extended) {
    opar <- par(usr = c(1, 1000, 1, 1000), mgp = c(1, 1, 
                                                   0))
    on.exit(par(opar), add = TRUE)
  }
  else {
    pin <- par("pin")
    rtxt <- "Standardized\nResiduals:"
    rtxtCex <- min(1, pin[1L]/(strheight(rtxt, units = "inches") * 
                                 12), pin[2L]/(strwidth(rtxt, units = "inches")/4))
    rtxtWidth <- 0.1
    opar <- par(usr = c(1, 1000 * (1.1 + rtxtWidth), 1, 1000), 
                mgp = c(1, 1, 0))
    on.exit(par(opar), add = TRUE)
    rtxtHeight <- strwidth(rtxt, units = "i", cex = rtxtCex)/pin[2L]
    text(1000 * (1.05 + 0.5 * rtxtWidth), 0, labels = rtxt, 
         adj = c(0, 0.25), srt = 90, cex = rtxtCex)
    len <- length(shade) + 1
    bh <- 0.95 * (0.95 - rtxtHeight)/(2 * len)
    x.l <- 1000 * 1.05
    x.r <- 1000 * (1.05 + 0.7 * rtxtWidth)
    y.t <- 1000 * rev(seq.int(from = 0.95, by = -bh, length.out = 2 * 
                                len))
    y.b <- y.t - 1000 * 0.8 * bh
    ltype <- c(rep.int(2, len), rep.int(1, len))
    for (i in 1:(2 * len)) {
      polygon(c(x.l, x.r, x.r, x.l), c(y.b[i], y.b[i], 
                                       y.t[i], y.t[i]), col = color[i], lty = ltype[i], 
              border = border)
    }
    brks <- round(breaks, 2)
    y.m <- y.b + 1000 * 0.4 * bh
    text(1000 * (1.05 + rtxtWidth), y.m, c(paste0("<", brks[2L]), 
                                           paste(brks[2:(2 * len - 1)], brks[3:(2 * len)], sep = ":"), 
                                           paste0(">", brks[2 * len])), srt = 90, cex = cex.axis, 
         xpd = NA)
  }
  if (!is.null(main) || !is.null(xlab) || !is.null(ylab) || 
      !is.null(sub)) 
    title(main, sub = sub, xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab)
  adj.x <- adj.y <- 0.5
  x1 <- 30 + 20 * cex.axis/0.66
  y1 <- 5
  x2 <- 950
  y2 <- 1000 - x1
  maxlen.xlabel <- maxlen.ylabel <- 35 * cex.axis/0.66
  if (srt.x == 90) {
    maxlen.xlabel <- max(strwidth(label[[dimd + 1L - match("v", 
                                                           rev(dir))]], cex = cex.axis))
    adj.x <- 1
    y2 <- y2 - maxlen.xlabel
  }
  if (srt.y == 0) {
    maxlen.ylabel <- max(strwidth(label[[match("h", dir)]], 
                                  cex = cex.axis))
    adj.y <- 0
    x1 <- x1 + maxlen.ylabel
  }
  mosaic.cell(Ind, x1 = x1, y1 = y1, x2 = x2, y2 = y2, srt.x = srt.x,
              srt.y = srt.y, adj.x = adj.x, adj.y = adj.y, off = off/100,
              dir = dir, color = color, lablevx = 2, lablevy = 2,
              maxdim = apply(as.matrix(Ind[, 1L:dimd]), 2L, max),
              currlev = 1, label = label)

  ## new stuff
  at <- seq(x1, x2, length.out = 6)
  axis(1, at, (at - min(at)) / diff(range(at)))
  invisible()
}
```