# Use of geom_mosaic (ggmosaic package) for predefined fill heights

Tags: r, ggmosaic

I am trying to understand how to use geom_mosaic with fill based on a proportion and the width of the bar based on the number of observations.  Basically I would like to recreate the answer given by @Z.Lin on the post [How to create a Marimekko/Mosaic plot in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233365/how-to-create-a-marimekko-mosaic-plot-in-ggplot2%20/%22how%20to%20create%20a%20marimekko%20mosaic%20plot%20in%20ggplot2%22)

The data is as follows:

```
 df <- diamonds %>%
  group_by(cut, clarity) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  mutate(cut.count = sum(count),
         prop = count/sum(count)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

So I would like:

- 1 bar per cut
- fill colour according to clarity (but fill height according to prop)
- width of bar defined by cut.count

My attempt, below, does not scale the fill height by prop (so essentially the y argument is ignored), I have tried supplying stat="identity" to geom_mosaic but receive an error message regarding ymin, ymax, xmin, xmax.

```
ggplot(df,aes(weight=cut.count, x = product(cut), y = product(prop), fill = clarity)) +
  geom_mosaic()
```

My real data is also pre-summarised

Comment: As I do not undestand fully what you wanna do so we can start here
`ggplot(df,aes(weight=cut.count, x = cut, y = prop, fill = clarity)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")`
what do you want to change here

Comment: The widths of the bar are the same and not in proportion to cut.count.