# Modify the colors in geom_mosaic() plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmosaic

I want to plot a mosaic plot with `ggplot2` and choose the colors manually, i.e, pick the colors for each category (A, B, C, D, E, F) on the y axis. Currently, I can only select the colors for each category on the x axis (X, Y, Z) with the `scale_fill_brewer()` command.

```
bd <- data.frame(x = c(120,5,15,5,20,100, 400,15,50,80,45,410, 250,15,75,35,40,250), 
y = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), 3),
         z = c(rep("X",6),rep("Y",6),rep("Z",6)))
bd$weight = bd$x/sum(bd$x)

ggplot(bd) +
  geom_mosaic(aes(x = product(y, z), 
                  fill = z, weight = weight), offset = 0.015) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette=2) +
  #scale_color_brewer(palette=3) +
  theme_mosaic()
```

**Output:**

[image: mosaic plot]

And I wanted something like in the [graphs provided in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64918446/creating-a-mosaic-plot-with-percentages).
This seems really easy, but I can't seem to find the answer. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned in your OP that you were interested in setting the fill colors manually, here is a way to do that. In @stefan answer you just need to substitute the `scale_fill_brewer(palette=2)` line for the following:

```
scale_fill_manual(values = c("A" = "firebrick2",
                             "B" = "royalblue",
                             "C" = "gold2",
                             "D" = "orchid2",
                             "E" = "forestgreen",
                             "F" = "orange2"))
```

You can consult some predefined color names in `ggplot2` here: [ggplot colors](http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2/colour).

[image: manual fill values mosaic plot]

Comment: Even better! Exatcly what I wanted, being able to pick exactly the colors I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to color by the `y` axis categories you have to map this variable on `fill`, i.e. do `fill = y`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmosaic)

ggplot(bd) +
  geom_mosaic(aes(
    x = product(y, z),
    fill = y, weight = weight
  ), offset = 0.015) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 2) +
  theme_mosaic()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for clarifying what I was missing.