# how to draw a percent stacked bar plot from two distinct binary-valued columns in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, bar-chart, mosaic-plot

I have two binary-valued columns in foods dataframe as follows:

```
foods$veryHealthy:

"False" "False" "True"  "True"  "False" "False" "False" "True"  "False" "False" "True"  "False"

"True"  "False" "False" "True"  "False" "True"  "False" "False" "True"  "False" "False" "False" ...

foods$dairyFree:

"True"  "True"  "True"  "True"  "True"  "True"  "True"  "True"  "False" "True"  "True"  "False"

"True"  "False" "False" "True"  "True"  "True"  "True"  "False" "True"  "False" "True"  "True" ...

I want to get some plot like:
```

[image: ![]

for the x-axis instead of four categories I want to use binary values.

notice how thickness of bars changes based on the number of instances in each class.

I have tried the following code but it did not get me the result:

```r
ggplot(foods, aes(x=veryHealthy, y=dairyFree, fill=dairyFree)) + 
  geom_col(position = "fill")
```

edit: I have to use ggplot2 and not any built-in or other libararies.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for the package [`ggmosaic`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggmosaic/index.html) here you can find the [vingette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggmosaic/vignettes/ggmosaic.html) for some examples:

```
# dummy data
df <- data.frame(veryHealthy = c("False","False","True","True","False","False","False","True","False","False","True","False","True","False","False","True","False","True","False","False","True","False","False","False"),
                 dairyFree = c("True","True","True","True","True","True","True","True","False","True","True","False","True","False","False","True","True","True","True","False","True","False","True","True"))

library(ggplot2)
library(ggmosaic)

# simple implementation with your dummy data
ggplot2::ggplot(data = df) +
    ggmosaic::geom_mosaic(aes(x = product(veryHealthy, dairyFree), fill = veryHealthy ))
```

[image]

EDIT:

maybe this does the work for you (using the same dummy data as before):

```
plot(table(df))
```

[image]

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233365/how-to-create-a-marimekko-mosaic-plot-in-ggplot2) you can find some "manual" aproaches

Comment: thanks for answering, but I have to use ggplot2 itself. I'm sorry I did not explicitly emphasize it.

Comment: @Hamed have a look at the altered answer... possibly this does the job the way you need it